# convert lists of tuples that contain lists into one json array

Tags: python, arrays, json, list, tuples

I have lists of tuples, where some of the tuples contain lists as the first element. I need to convert this list into json array.

I have also read up on this issue on StackOverflow, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702684/python-list-of-node-id-parent-node-id-to-json), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19795012/how-to-convert-a-list-to-jsonarray-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37805772/tuples-conversion-into-json-with-python) and many others, however none of which address directly the issue.

I have tried the following approach, as found [here](https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/tuple/python-tuple-exercise-19.php)
In this approach, each list that I have is generated after iterating through each line of a txt file and performaring an operation on each line.

Example code:

**infile**:

```
Dalmations are white and yes they are pets who live at home.
Huskies tend to be grey and can be pets who also live at home.
Pitbulls usually are beige and can be pets who sometimes live at home.
```

**sample code**:

```
inFile = '/data/sample.txt'
f = open(inFile, 'r').readlines()

def Convert(tup, di):
    for a, b in tup:
        di.setdefault(a[0]).append(b)
    return di


dictionary = {}

for line in f:
    keyTerms = extractTerms(line)
    print keyTerms
```

**result of extractTerms**

```
[(u'dalmations', u'dog'), (u'white', u'color'), (u'yes', u'pet'), (u'house', u'location')]
[(u'huskies', u'dog'), (u'grey', u'color'), (u'yes', u'pet'),(u'house',u'location')]
[(u'pitbulls', u'dog'), (u'beige', u'color'), (u'yes', u'pet'),(u'house',u'location')]
```

---

```
    allTerms = [(expandAllKeyTerms(a), b) for (a,b) in keyTerms]

    print allTerms

[([u'dalmations', u'dalmation', u'dalmashun', u'dalmationz'], u'dog'), ([u'white'], u'color'), ([u'yes'], u'pet'), ([u'home'], u'location')]
    [([u'huskies', u'husky', u'huskies'], u'dog'), ([u'grey'], u'color'), ([u'yes'], u'pet'), ([u'home'], u'location')]
    [([u'pitbulls'], u'dog'), ([u'beige'], u'color'), ([u'yes'], u'pet'), ([u'home'], u'location')]

new = (Convert(allTerms, dictionary))
print new
```

**sample (wrong) final output:**

```
{u'dog': [u'dalmations', u'huskies', u'pitbulls'], u'color': [u'white', u'grey', u'beige'], u'pet': [u'yes', u'yes', u'yes'], u'location': [u'home', u'home', u'home']}
```

I have also tried using `import json` // `json.dumps(dictionary)`, however, it also associates all of the values to the one corresponding key in stead of maintaing each individual line as its own entry.

My goal is to arrive at the following format

```
[{u'dog': [u'dalmations'], u'color': [u'white'], u'pet': [u'yes'], u'location': [u'home']};
{u'dog': [u'huskies'], u'color': [u'grey'], u'pet': [u'yes'], u'location': [u'home']};
{u'dog': [ u'pitbulls'], u'color': [u'beige'], u'pet': [u'yes'], u'location': [u'home']}]
```

Is there a way to arrive at my desires output using json library or another list comprehension?

Comment: Show the source for `extractTerms` and  `expandAllKeyTerms`

Comment: @GarbageCollector the sources are external functions and long code. i provide the output of each individual function though if that helps to contextualize more

Comment: A dictionary can't have multiple entries with the same key - is that what you're trying to do? In that case, your list of lists (or list of tuples) would work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below seems to work. Might work for your whole data set depending on what you're looking to do (how flexible you need things to be).

```
#!/usr/env python3

import json


a = [
    [
        ('dalmations', 'dog'),
        ('white', 'color'),
        ('yes', 'pet'),
        ('house', 'location'),
    ],
    [
        ('huskies', 'dog'),
        ('grey', 'color'),
        ('yes', 'pet'),
        ('house','location')
    ],
    [
        ('pitbulls', 'dog'),
        ('beige', 'color'),
        ('yes', 'pet'),
        ('house','location')
    ]
]

b = []
for row in a:
    data = {}
    for word in row:
        data[word[1]] = [word[0],]
    b.append(data)

print(json.dumps(b))
```

This gives:

```
[
  {
    "color": ["white"],
    "pet": ["yes"],
    "dog": ["dalmations"],
    "location": ["house"]
  },
  {
    "color": ["grey"],
    "pet": ["yes"],
    "dog": ["huskies"],
    "location": ["house"]
  },
  {
    "color": ["beige"], 
    "pet": ["yes"], 
    "dog": ["pitbulls"], 
    "location": ["house"]
  }
]
```